# How to center widget inside QStackedLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QProgressBar that I need to be centered inside QStackedLayout. How can I achieve it, given that QStackedLayout::setAlignment doesn't have any effect, and the widget is always in the top-left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the QProgressBar in a container (i.e. QWidget) that allows it to be centered with an additional layout.